# DataGrid selected value coulndn't accessible, it was fetching anonymous type object

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've a datagrid that bound the data person, place and amount. In the SelectionChanged event I was tried to access the data but it was saying the type is Anonymous.

[image]

How do Convert this object and acquire the value ?

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: what's the DataGrid's ItemSource type?

Comment: I'm getting the source from the Entity Model table

Comment: var objResult = from c in objEntities.PersonAccounts
                            select new { c.PersonName, c.Amount, c.Place };

            workgrid.ItemsSource = objResult;

Comment: This is the way which i'm updating the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Reflection to get the property values.

```
private void workgrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    object selectedItem = ((DataGrid)sender).SelectedItem;
    Type type = selectedItem.GetType(); 

    string name = (string)type.GetProperty("PersonName").GetValue(selectedItem, null);
    int amount = (int)type.GetProperty("Amount").GetValue(selectedItem, null);
    string place = (string)type.GetProperty("Place").GetValue(selectedItem, null);
}
```

Though, the recommend way is to create your own type for a collection that you will use to bind your DataGrid to. This will allow you to avoid binding directly to an anonymous type.

```
public class AccountInfo
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's useful. Thanks for your valuable solution